# Typescript: Restrict function arg type to type of specific class, not allowing inherited type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

On the example below, I have a function `foo` that accepts a single argument with type `A`.

```
export function foo<T extends A>(arg: A) {
  console.log(arg.propA);
  // do something with arg
  return arg as unknown as A & B & T;
}

class A {
  propA: string;
  constructor() {
    this.propA = "A";
  }
}

class B extends A {
  propB: string;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.propB = "B";
  }
}

class C {
  propC: string;
  constructor() {
    this.propC = "C";
  }
}
```

when I call `foo`, I'm looking for a static ts error to appear on the second call.

```
const processedA = foo(new A()); // okay

foo(processedA); // okay, but i want this to error

foo(new C()); // error as expected
```

I'm thinking along the lines of "if arg has additional keys other than that defined from A" but I can't figure out how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: ①  Does a "static ts error" just mean "ts error" as opposed to a runtime error? ② Why is `foo` generic at all, when the `arg` argument is of type `A` and not `T`? Is that a typo or intentional?  Either way, could you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: i'd wan't `new B()` to be rejected as well. basically, just want to restrict `foo` to only accept type `A` or in my thinking, at least an object that doesnt have additional properties to `A`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nn5nkw) meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining or find a suitable dupe target. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: that basically nailed it. thank you kind sir. Also noted on that aliasing part.

Comment: See the answers to the linked questions, and [this comment on ms/TS#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-368244671)... as well as the whole ms/TS#12936 which asks for "exact types", which TS doesn't really have.

Comment: I see there's a whole can of worms going on there. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The type `A & B` has type

```
{
  propA: string;
  propB: string;
}
```

so it is correctly not an error.

That is because the types are treated as open types.
So the type of A can equivalently be written as

```
{
  propA: string;
}
& {
  [k:string]: unknown
}
```

---

UPDATE:

The behavior when assigning a new key+value does NOT follow the open principal:

```
type A = { propa: string};
type B = { propb: string};

const x: Readonly<A> & Readonly<B> = {propa: "", propb: ""};
x.propc = ""; // error
// Property 'propc' does not exist on type 'A & B'. Did you mean 'propa'?(2551)
x.propa = "a"; // error
// Cannot assign to 'propa' because it is a read-only property.(2540)

const y: A & B = {propa: "", propb: ""};
y.propc = ""; // error
// Property 'propc' does not exist on type 'A & B'. Did you mean 'propa'?(2551)
y.propa = "a"; // no error

const z: A & B & { [k:string]: any } = {propa: "", propb: ""};
z.propc = ""; // error
// Property 'propc' does not exist on type 'A & B'. Did you mean 'propa'?(2551)
z.propa = "a"; // error
```

So actually it is neither completely open type or closed type.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. however, is there a way to restrict the type to only accept `{
  propA: string;
}`. In reality however, `A` will have a handful of other properties included so I'd ideally want to define a typing that makes use of `A` (instead of `{
  propA: string;
}`) if that makes any sense.

Comment: added some more info.

Comment: thanks, Craig! [jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz) has provided a working solution.